# to many re-renders error react, how to avoid it

Tags: reactjs

hope you can help with this issue:

I have been struggling to try to find the way how to clear interval in react, I am having an error everytime I run the code saying that there are many re-renders, I have been trying for so long in google how to clear interval function in react but I just couldn't find a working way for me, I would like to call the clear interval if the condition

```
if(verification.length===6){
      setSpinner()
        console.log('works')
  }
```

I hope it will be enough for react to accept my dirty code.

here is the rest of the code:

```
import "./PaymentPage.scss";
import Spinner from "../../components/Spinner/Spinner";

export default function PaymentPage() {
    const [status, setStatus] = useState(false);
    const [alert, setAlert] = useState(true);
    const [spinner, setSpinner] = useState(true);
    const [verification, setVerification] = useState("");
    
  
  if(verification.length===6){
   
      setSpinner()
        console.log('works')
  }
    

const verifier=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    
   
    if(number.length>=16 && name!=='' && expiry!=='' && cvc.length>=3){
        setStatus(true)
        console.log('alert',status)
        setInterval(print,500);**//if the condition above is accomplished i call the interval.**
       
    }else{
        setAlert(false)
        console.log('alert',alert)
    }

}
const print=()=>{

    setVerification(verification=> verification+".");**//it will add a '.' on every iteration**

}


useEffect(() => {
     
    console.log('cc details', number,name,expiry,cvc,expiry)
   

}, [status])
```

thank you all in advance and sorry for my probably stupid question

Comment: `setSpinner()` needs parameter. What are you trying to set in the spinner state? also can you show your return statement of the payment page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The useEffect should be used otherwise it will keep on rendering once verification.length ===6 becomes true. This will render only once when verification.length becomes 6.

```
useEffect(() => {
     
  if(verification.length===6){

      setSpinner()   

    }
}, [verification])
```

Comment: you can mark it as answered so that other users are benefitted